# Laravel - getting many to many relation along with condition check in another table

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a many to many relation with users and questions table using a pivot table question_user. It is used to assign question to a user.  Also I have another table which stores the answer with user_id and question_id.  How do I query the questions of a user which are not answered, using a single query ? When I try the following query I am getting all the questions assigned to the user including the answered one.

```
$questions = Question::leftJoin('answers', 'answers.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
            ->leftJoin('question_user', 'questions.id' ,'=','question_user.question_id')
            ->where('question_user.user_id',$user->id)->where('answers.question_id','!=','question_user.question_id')
            ->select('questions.*')->groupBy('questions.id')->paginate(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$unAnsweredQuestion =
    Question::whereNotIn("id", DB::raw("select question_id from question_user where user_id ={$user->id}"))
               -> select('question.*') -> paginate(30);
```